# Unable to use tts with rails configured with passenger and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, httprequest, passenger

I have a rails 3.2 application that has been configured to work with phusion passenger and apache.
Normal requests are running fine on my server, however when the tts gem attempts to connect to the google tts server through the rails app i get the following error

```
 SystemExit in DemoController#call
    exit
```

And

```
app/controllers/demo_controller.rb:24:in `call'
```

This is the relevent part of my demo controller.

```
require 'tts'
require "open-uri"
require "net/https"
require 'json'

class DemoController < ApplicationController


    def call

    string1 = "Testing in file one"
    string1.to_file "en", "file1.mp3" 

    end

end
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of googling, finally got a solution.
The problem is that the gem did not get enough permissions to execute system commands. This was not a problem of passenger blocking requests.
An easy way to solve this problem is giving passenger enough permissions to do do the necessary tasks.
Consider  a sample :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Change these 3 lines to suit your project
    RailsEnv development
    ServerName xyz.abc.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/app/public
   <Directory /home/user/app/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    PassengerHighPerformance on
    PassengerSpawnMethod direct

</VirtualHost>
```

These to lines have to be added to the code

```
    PassengerUser root
    PassengerDefaultUser root
```

Comment: You do know that running your app as root is extremely dangerous, right? Passenger goes into great lengths to prevent you from running your app as root, but if you override all that then any security vulnerabilities you might face are entirely at your own risk.

Comment: i could not find any other viable solution. The only other solution i know of is giving permissions 777 to everything inside the rails application